# Writing a function that scrapes dataset that appears only after typing in values and clicking a button

Tags: r, http, web-scraping, sas

I am trying to write a function that will take a list of dates and retrieve the dataset as found on https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm

I am using PROC IML in SAS to execute R-code (since I am more familiar with R).

My problem is within R, and is due to the website.

First, I am aware that there is an API but this is an exercise I really want to learn because many sites do not have APIs.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the datasets?

Things I've heard:

1. Use RSelenium to program the clicking. RSelenium got taken off of the archive recently so that isn't an option (even downloading it off of a previous version is causing issues).
2. Look at the XML url changes as I click the "submit" button in Chrome. However, the XML in the Network tab doesn't show anything, whereas on other websites that have different methods of searching do.

I have been looking for a solution all day, but to no avail! Please help

Comment: You can still [install RSelenium from GitHub](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/172#issuecomment-389034374) or use [splashr](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr), but generally if there is an API, you should use the API.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'll have to see what I can do with RSelenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to read the terms and conditions and make sure that you are not breaking the rules when scraping.

Next, if there is an API, you should use it so that they can better manage their data usage and operations.

In addition, you should also limit the number of requests made so as not to overload the server. If I am not wrong, this is related to DNS Denial of Service attacks.

Finally, if those above conditions are satisfied, you can use the inspector on Chrome to see what HTTP requests are being made when you browse these webpages.

In this particular case, you do not need RSelenium and a simple HTTP POST will do

```
library(httr)

resp <- POST("https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm",
    body=list(
        priceDate.month=5,
        priceDate.day=15,
        priceDate.year=2018,
        submit="CSV+Format"
    ),
    encode="form")

read.csv(text=rawToChar(resp$content), header=FALSE)
```

Comment: You can use `httr::content` to extract the response: `httr::content(resp, type = 'text/csv', col_names = FALSE)`

Comment: the most impt thing is please do not break the rules

Comment: From what I've read, shouldn't be an issue... should I add a lag to the request, just in case? Not sure what legal issue is in particular interest here!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the same http processing in a SAS session using `Proc HTTP`.  The CSV data does not contain a header row, so perhaps the XML Format is more appropriate.  There are a couple of caveats for the treasurydirect site.

- Prior to posting a data download request the connection needs some cookies that are assigned during a GET request.  Proc HTTP can do this.
- The XML contains an extra tag container `<bpd>` that the SAS XMLV2 library engine can't handle simply.  This extra tag can be removed with some DATA step processing.

Sample code for XML

```
filename response TEMP;
filename respfilt TEMP;

* Get request sets up fresh session and cookies;
proc http
  clear_cache 
  method = "get"
  url ="https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm"
;
run;

* Post request as performed by XML format button;
* automatically utilizes cookies setup in GET request;
* in= can now directly specify the parameter data to post;

proc http 
  method = "post"
  in = 'priceDate.year=2018&priceDate.month=5&priceDate.day=15&submit=XML+Format'
  url ="https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm"
  out = response
;
run;

* remove bpd tag from the response (the downloaded xml);

data _null_;
  infile response;
    file respfilt;
  input;
  if _infile_ not in: ('<bpd', '</bpd');
  put _infile_;
run;

* copy data collections from xml file to tables in work library;

libname respfilt xmlv2 ;

proc copy in=respfilt out=work;
run;
```

Reference material

> REST at Ease with SAS®: How to Use SAS to Get Your REST
>   Joseph Henry, SAS Institute Inc., Cary, NC
>   http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings16/SAS6363-2016.pdf